# Changing variable from object in list (c++)

Tags: c++, list, variables

I want to change for example set the 'Voornaam' from the object that is in the list. But for some reason if I display the objects in list with another function its not changed.

I have made a function "showWielrennerGegevens(*iter);", this will show all variables from that object. If this function is run, then I can see the changes. But not if I run the function to show object in the list

Please help

```
void Interface::wijzigPersoneelslid(Wielerploeg& wielerploegOB){

int input,inputWielrennerID,ingavekeuze;
string ingaveString;

int teller=0;

cout << "Wat voor een type wil je wijzigen?" << endl;
cout << "1 - Wielrenner" << endl;
cout << "2 - Dokter" << endl;
cout << "3 - Mecanicien" << endl;
cin >> input;

switch(input)
{
    case 1:{//Wielrenner
        cout << "Wielrenner" << endl;

        list<Wielrenner> wielrennerslist = wielerploegOB.getWielrennersList();
        cout << "Welke wielrenner wil je wijzigen?" << endl;

        // Alle objecten afprinten in de lijst
        for (list<Wielrenner>::iterator it = wielrennerslist.begin(); it != wielrennerslist.end(); it++){
            Wielrenner wielrennerOB = *it;
            cout << teller << " - " << wielrennerOB.getVoornaam() << " " << wielrennerOB.getAchternaam() << endl;
            teller++;
        }
        cin >> inputWielrennerID;

        // Naar het object gaan
        int N = inputWielrennerID; /* index of the element you want to retrieve */
        if (wielrennerslist.size() > N){
            list<Wielrenner>::iterator iter = wielrennerslist.begin();
            std::advance(iter, N);

            // 'it' points to the element at index 'N'

            Wielrenner wielrennerOB2 = *iter;
            //Wielrenner* wielrennerOB2 = *iter;

            cout << "\n De geselecteerde wielrenner is: " << endl;
            cout << " - " << wielrennerOB2.getVoornaam() << wielrennerOB2.getAchternaam() << endl;

            cout << "\n Wat wil je aanpassen?" << endl;
            cout << "1 - Voornaam" << endl;
            cout << "2 - Achternaam" << endl;
            cout << "3 - Telefoon" << endl;
            cin >> ingavekeuze;
            switch(ingavekeuze)                                                                                                                                                 
            {
                case 1:{ // voornaam
                    cout << "Ingave voornaam: ";
                    cin >> ingaveString;
                    //wielrennerOB2.setVoornaam(ingaveString);
                    (*iter).setVoornaam(ingaveString);

                    cout << "object " << endl;
                    showWielrennerGegevens(*iter);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{ // achternaam
                    cout << "Ingave achternaam: ";
                    cin >> ingaveString;
                    wielrennerOB2.setAchternaam(ingaveString);

                    cout << "object " << endl;
                    showWielrennerGegevens(wielrennerOB2);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:{ // telefoon
                    cout << "Ingave telefoon: ";
                    cin >> ingaveString;
                    wielrennerOB2.setTelefoon(ingaveString);
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    cout << "Switch Default waarde - wielrenner wijzig" << endl;
                }
            }
        }// if statement
        break;
    }// case 1
    case 2:{ // dokter
        cout << "Dokter" << endl;
        break;
    }
    default:{
        cout << "Switch Default waarde - Interface" << endl;
    }
} // switch
```

}

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you have made a copy of your list. You are changing the copy but not the original.

```
list<Wielrenner> wielrennerslist = wielerploegOB.getWielrennersList();
```

This line makes a copy of the list.

What to do next is harder to say. Perhaps you need to do this?

```
list<Wielrenner> wielrennerslist = wielerploegOB.getWielrennersList();
...
// make change to wielrennerslist 
...
// copy changed list back to original
wielerploegOB.setWielrennersList(wielrennerslist);
```

This will work only if you have a method setWielrennersList, if not then maybe you should write one.

Comment: So the function setWielrennersList(wielrennerslist) will then replace the new list with the previous one?

Comment: @Sharpless512 No the other way around. It should replace the previous list with the new changed list.

Comment: It worked, this is my function:
void Wielerploeg::setWielrennerList(list<Wielrenner> newWielrennerList){
 wielrenners = newWielrennerList;
}

Comment: @Sharpless512 why all the copies? Can't you return a reference to a list from `wielerploegOB`?

Comment: Can you give an example how I can do this?

Comment: Returning references to internal class members is bad style IMO.

Comment: @Sharpless512 Your setWielrennerList function looks good. However there's a quick way you can improve it `void Wielerploeg::setWielrennerList(const list<Wielrenner>& newWielrennerList){ wielrenners = newWielrennerList; }`. By using a reference you potentially save making a temporary copy of the list when you call the function. I can see that it would be a good time for you to learn all about references.

Comment: @jahhaj it isn't bad style if the only purpose of the class is to hold and provide the data. That is pretty common practice in standard library containers.